How can I query the System.Id to get only the number
Currently I'm using this command to query the details of the az boards,
but I only need the System.Id number 0941248, is there a way to filter this out?
az boards query --wiql "SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitems WHERE [System.State] IN ('New') and [System.Title] = '[Test ticket] CVE found for mssql'"
and here is the output:
[
  {
    "fields": {
      "System.Id": 0941248
    },
    "id": 0941248,
    "relations": null,
    "rev": 1,
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/PROD/_apis/wit/workItems/0941248"
  }
]


You can use below powershell to get the System.Id:
$jsonOutput = az boards query --wiql "SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitems WHERE [System.State] IN ('New') and [System.Title] = '[Test ticket] CVE found for mssql'" | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Output $jsonOutput.fields.'System.id'


On Ubuntu with Bash, you can install jq via comamnd sudo apt-get install jq, then get the target id:
az boards query --wiql "SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitems WHERE [System.State] IN ('New') and [System.Title] = '[Test ticket] CVE found for mssql'" | jq '.[].fields."System.Id"'


is there a way to use this on bash?
I'm getting this error message
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe```

On bash, you can use jq to get the id. I will edit the answer with details, please check, thanks.

You are welcome, glad to help! Happy day!

Happy day to you too!
